# migrate one ldap server to another - questions

Tags: passwords, ldap, migration, ldif

We have an existing Sun DS(6.3 version) in Solaris that we are planning to migrate to ODSEE in Linux and have couple of questions regarding the migration.

Based on readings, I think LDIF option is the best one, but the question is about the passwords. The passwords are in SSHA format and we would like to preserve the same passwords. If we do LDIF export/import, would that work? The users need to be able to use the same passwords. What are the things I need to do to make sure the passwords are migrated properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Sun Directory Server (all versions, including ODSEE) will import and preserve hashed passwords. The same is true for OpenDJ which was initially designed (as the OpenDS project) to replace Sun DSEE.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there anything else that needs to be copied over like SSL certs. Also how is the Salted SHA passwords migrated, won't the hash be different. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this and it works. I got an ldif which had 3 test users and imported the ldif in another completely different VM and the user logins were successful.